# Pasar valor de un combobox a otro label de otro formulario en visual basic

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Hola buenas tardes Familia .
una consulta como puedo pasar valor de un combobox a otro label de otro formulario yo estoy realizando en mi primer formulario este codigo:

```
 Private Sub DtgImportar_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DtgImportar.CellDoubleClick
    Try
        ivIncidencia = 0
        ivIncidencia = DtgImportar.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value()
        Me.Close()

        FrmAtencion.Show()
        CboUsuario.Text = FrmAtencion.lblusuarioanterior.Text

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "..:: Aviso del Sistema ::..")
        Exit Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

pero cuando voy a mi otro formulario ese label esta vacio

Comment: Estas enviando un Me.Close() antes del .Show() del otro formulario eso hace que tu formulario (y su código) se cierren antes de poder cargar el otro Label. He ahi el problema.

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres hacer es poner el valor del combo CboUsuario en el label lblusuarioanterior debes seguir este orden:

```
        FrmAtencion.lblusuarioanterior.Text = CboUsuario.Text;
        FrmAtencion.Show();
```

Te recomendaria usar metodos publicos para realizar esto y darle más transparencia al codigo algo como esto:

```
FrmAtencion atencion = new FrmAtencion();
atencion.SetearLabel(CboUsuario.Text);
atencion.Show();
```

Y dentro del form FrmAtencion poner:

```
public void SetearLabel(string texto){
  lblusuarioanterior.Text = texto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo suelo hacer del siguiente modo:

En el formulario al que quieres llamar (creo que es FrmAtencion) pondría lo siguiente:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Usuario as string)
     Me.lblusuarioanterior.Text = Usuario
End Sub
```

Y en el formulario desde el que lo llamas pondría:

```
Dim f as New FrmAtencion(CboUsuario.Text)
f.Show()
Me.Close()
```